# show x and y label in corrplot given residuals of chisq.test

Tags: r

Here is some reproducible code:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(
    x = round(runif(n = 100, min = 1, max = 3), 0)
    , y = round(runif(n = 100, min = 1, max = 3), 0)
)

chisq <- chisq.test(
    df$x
    ,df$y
    , simulate.p.value = TRUE
)
chisq

options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5) 
corrplot(chisq$residuals, is.cor = FALSE, xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

I would like the corrplot to show the label x and y. I think xlab and ylab should work but it does not. Any ideas? Thanks!